# uncompress wavelet compressed image

Tags: image, wavelet, compression

I have an wavelet compressed image, but not sure what parameter its using for compression, is there a way to un-compress this image?. I tried using a jpeg-2000 image viewer but it did not help. 
As per my understanding one should know the wavelet on which it was compressed to proceed further, but this information is missing at present. Does this mean the images remain encrypted and cant be decoded?

Comment: Is this a .WI CorelDraw format file? Did you ever succeed? @letap

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the data format? if you plot it can you see the main bands and sub bands at the various levels of detail?

Once you have the data format, you can simply try a few possible wavelet shapes, starting with the Haar for simplicity. At least you will get a good impression of the image content.

If you don't know the data format, you are probably stuffed.